# How to turn on/off IDENTITY_INSERT in Redshift

Tags: sequence, amazon-redshift

I have to turn off the identity on a table in redshift and insert the historical values into that.

If I try to insert values into an identity column I am getting below error

ERROR: 0A000: cannot set an identity column to a value

Comment: If your table will contain only historical values and the column you specified as identity will have duplicate data, then what is the use of creating that column as identity?

Comment: Unable to turn off Identity in a Redshift table is a huge drawback. That means, for every reload of Dimension, Fact table has to be reloaded with new surrogate keys.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by following simple 2 step approach.

1. unload the historical table data and put it into file @s3
2. run copy command against this file to load target table by
   specifying  `explicit_ids` as parameter in your copy command.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to switch off identity values in Redshift. If the order of your identity is independent of records being new or historical, you can just insert the historical records and they will be inserted with new values for the identity key.